# postHandle method is not invoking after http request handling

Tags: java, security, spring-boot, interceptor, spring-web

I've created following component to add `X-Frame-Options` into each response:

```
@Component
public class SecurityInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("init");
    }
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
    }
}
```

method `init` executes on startup thus spring knows about this.

Also I have following rest service:

```
@PostMapping("/rest_upload")
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    final DeferredResult<ResponseEntity> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
    ...
    return deferredResult;
}
```

Unfortunately postHandle method is not invoking.

How can I correct it?

Comment: have you registered this interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring knows about your Interceptor as just a bean and nothing more. You need to register it with `InterceptorRegistry` so that it is called as part of interceptors.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired 
  SecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor;

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(securityInterceptor); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a configuration class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and overrides the addInterceptor method:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new SecurityInterceptor());
}
```

You also need to make sure you have enabled WebMvc in Spring.

Comment: Implementing WebMvcConfigurer is enough now. WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated now.